# ChronoMate: why can't I see my projects?

Tags: freshbooks-api

Once I authorized the ChronoMate app with FreshBooks, I could still not see my client's project in the list.

1. I made sure that the project was assigned to the client under the
   Clients tab.
2. I made sure that the staff member (the one authorized in the app) was assigned to the client.

Yet it still didn't list the client's projects in ChronoMate.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the client is not archived.

1. Go to People > Clients.
2. Click the archived link at the bottom of the list.
3. Select the client and click Un-archive.
4. Go to ChronoMate and press the Pull button.

The client and their projects should appear in the drop-down now.